# Html flip card doesn't work on mobile and freeze links on the page

Tags: html, css

I created a page with flip cards, on desktop it works fine while on mobile the flip cards doesn't turn and freeze the links on the page.

I can't find what I have to change.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .flip-card {
    width: 240px;
    height: 360px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .book-description {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .description-author {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .book-reservation {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  .flip-card {
    width: 600px;
    height: 900px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
  }
  .book-description {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .description-author {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .book-reservation {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .flip-card {
    height: 240px;
  }
  .book-description {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  .description-author {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
  .book-reservation {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .flip-card {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .book-description {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .description-author {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .book-reservation {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.book-description {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: courier;
  color: black;
}

.book-cover {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #B53031;
}

.description-author {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: courier;
  font-style: italic;
  color: black;
}

.book-reservation {
  background-color: #b02b2c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.book-reservation:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #c43031;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bottone-pagina-2 {
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-radius: 14px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.bottone-pagina-2:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: FIREBRICK;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
Here the code:

<div class="col-md-3">





  <section class="WidgetHolder HtmlWidget first">



    <div class="flip-card">



      <div class="flip-card-inner">



        <div class="flip-card-front">



          <!-- inserire il link all'immagine della copertina del libro -->



          <img src=" https://milano.biblioteche.it/sites/milano/assets/CRESCENZAGO/Immagini-Crescenzago/97888997811700536075.jpg " alt="Avatar" class="book-cover">



        </div>



        <div class="flip-card-back">



          <p class="book-description">



            <!-- inserire la descrizione del libro -->



            Avere a cuore, conoscere e capire meglio il luogo in cui si è cresciuti o in cui si vive aiuta a ereditarne la tradizione e la vitalità. Questo è lo scopo degli autori: trasmettere ai lettori la storia del posto in cui hanno imparato a vivere, seguendo
            una tradizione ricca di umanità, solidarietà, religiosità e cultura. Ecco la storia di Crescenzago, storico quartiere milanese, raccontata per periodi secolari, con un focus sul Novecento, e arricchita da numerose immagini

          </p>







          <p class="description-author">



            <!-- inserire l'autore della recensione' -->





          </p>



          <!-- inserire il link a OPAC (al posto di #) -->



          <!-- recensione scritta da Cristina, bibliotecaria -->



        </div>



      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>











<div class="col-md-3">



  <section class="WidgetHolder HtmlWidget first">

    <div class="flip-card">

      <div class="flip-card-inner">

        <div class="flip-card-front">



          <img src=" https://milano.biblioteche.it/sites/milano/assets/CRESCENZAGO/Immagini-Crescenzago/Storia-di-cimiano.jpg?r=89914 " class="book-cover">

        </div>

        <div class="flip-card-back">

          <p class="book-description"> il libro rappresenta un utile contributo nella ricostruzione delle vicende storiche di Cimiano dall'età antica a quella contemporanea. Con particolare attenzione sono trattate le trasformazioni sociali e culturali avvenute soprattutto dalla
            metà del xx secolo. </p>



        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </section>







</div>









<div class="col-md-3">



  <section class="WidgetHolder HtmlWidget first">

    <div class="flip-card">

      <div class="flip-card-inner">

        <div class="flip-card-front">



          <img src=" https://milano.biblioteche.it/sites/milano/assets/CRESCENZAGO/Immagini-Crescenzago/dino-barra-via-padova.jpg?r=63808" alt="copertina libro" class="book-cover">

        </div>

        <div class="flip-card-back">

          <p class="book-description"> Via Padova è considerata una delle "strade simbolo" di Milano e da diversi anni è diventata archetipo di periferia, non solo nel capoluogo lombardo. È sinonimo di quartiere multietnico e mutante anticipatore di tendenze sociali all'interno dei
            territori metropolitani per le questioni della convivenza tra culture diverse e dei diritti dei più deboli. La via Padova che oggi conosciamo inizia a prendere forma attorno all'ultimo ventennio dell'Ottocento. </p>



        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </section>







</div>













<div class="col-md-12">



  <section class="WidgetHolder ContentWidget first">



  </section>







</div>









<div class="col-md-12">



  <section class="WidgetHolder HtmlWidget first">


  </section>



  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: hover event is not works on mobile.
Maybe you can add a checkbox for mobile and write a js command that unchecks it 2 seconds after it is clicked.
if checked the animation works.